# VS Code auto completion for imported JSON in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, visual-studio-code

Is there any way (configuration/plugin) to enable auto-completion for `JSON` documents which are imported using `require` or `import` keyword in `Node.js`?

I've searched and tried quite a few extensions but couldn't find any.